# Why hibernate connection provider doesn't set properly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, c3p0

Im using hibernate3 and springframework.

I want to set c3P0 Pool for hibernate.connection.provider_class but apparently **LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider** was set.

In Hibernate.log I see this:

> [Level: INFO]Initializing connection provider:
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider

I think *org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider* is hibernate default connection provider class for pooling and as I read it's wrong to use in production. Is that correct?

I want to set *org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider* and manage pool connection with c3p0

This is my hibernate config:

```
<bean id="c3p0Datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <value>.......</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>.......</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>.......</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="c3p0Datasource" />
    </property>     

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>     
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">.....</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">UPDATE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>             
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe C3P0 was set but I see "Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider" in log.

Is there other way to check that?